# How to make dynamic views available to multiple users?

Tags: scadalts

hello community,

I am using Scada LTS where multiple users will access my specific service, ie I have to make a group of views available to these users. The point is that if I have 100 users and each user accesses 5 pages I will have 500 pages.
How can I create dynamic views?

Comment: I'd need more details. I think you can do something like a dynamic view.